# Php erro api youtube

Tags: php, json

Estava usando até 2 semanas atrás o código abaixo para listar o nome do vídeo através da *API* do YouTube.

**Código:**

```
<?php

$dados ="Roberto Carlos";

$video_list = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q='.urlencode($dados).'&maxResults=3&key=AIzaSyAVittweX_WS_VQYypeYl5uDSWl2ti7PMc'));?>



<?php foreach($video_list->items as $item){?>


Titulo da musica : <?php echo $item->snippet->title;?>


<?php } ;?>
```

Agora está dando o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
> ```

Como posso resolver esse erro?

Comment: Essa key esta valida ?

Comment: Sim e valida ja testei

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Roberto%20Carlos&maxResults=3&key=AIzaSyAVittweX_WS_VQYypeYl5uDSWl2ti7PMc

Comment: da uma olha ai acima url

Comment: Ve a resposta dessa pergunta : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more provavelmente vai funcionar, se não servir comenta ai de novo

Comment: Ja tinha visto meu diretor mais não entendi e não consegui resolver

Comment: Aquela resposta ali mostra como desabilitar a verificação de pares, vai permitir conectar sem segurança, não tenho como testar um código agora, se ninguém responder amanhã eu faço uma resposta.

Comment: Ok meu diretor vou esperar

Comment: Oi meu diretor ainda esta por ai ?

Comment: Consegui dessa forma vou colocar em uma resposta o codigo

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74532/discussion-between-hemerson-prestes-and-anthraxisbr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece pois você não está configurando um certificado válido nas configurações do [*openssl*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.openssl.php) em seu PHP.

Há várias alternativas para corrigir ou "burlar" esse problema

---

#### Baixando e configurando um certificado válido

Caso você não possua um certificado SSL válido para configurar, poderá baixar no link https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem, após baixar esse certificado, basta adicionar o código abaixo em seu `php.ini` e depois reiniciar seu servidor.

```
openssl.cafile=/path/to/cacert.pem
```

> Utilize ferramentas como https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html, checar a validade de um certificado.

---

### Desabilitando o SSL no `file_get_contents`

Caso, por algum motivo, você não queira utilizar o SSL, você poderá criar um objeto [*stream_context*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stream-context-create.php). Nesse objeto você poderá informar que não deseja realizar uma requisição segura.

Na função `file_get_contents` podemos passar três parâmetros:

- `$filename`: Nome do arquivo ou URL;
- `$flags`: O modo como desejamos acessar o conteúdo (`FILE_BINARY`, `FILE_TEXT` etc);
- `$context`: Objeto criado a partir da função `stream_context_create`.

**Exemplo:**

```
<?php

$dados = "Roberto Carlos";
$url   = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q='.urlencode($dados).'&maxResults=3&key=AIzaSyAVittweX_WS_VQYypeYl5uDSWl2ti7PMc';

$stream = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [                 /* Configuração do openssl da requisição */
        'verify_peer' => false /* Ignora a necessidade do certificado e desabilita requisição segura */
    ]
]);

$result = file_get_contents($url, FILE_BINARY, $stream);

$video_list = json_decode($result);

foreach($video_list->items as $item){;
    var_dump($item->snippet->title);
}
```

---

### Informando um certificado com `file_get_contents`

Caso você tenha limitações em seu servidor e não possa modificar o arquivo `php.ini`, você pode utilizar o [stream_context](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stream-context-create.php) para informar o caminho do certificado que você gerou ou baixou, por exemplo:

```
<?php

$dados = "Roberto Carlos";
$url   = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q='.urlencode($dados).'&maxResults=3&key=AIzaSyAVittweX_WS_VQYypeYl5uDSWl2ti7PMc';

$stream = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [                               /* Configuração do openssl da requisição */
        'verify_peer' => true,               /* Habilita requisição segura */
        'cafile'      => '/pasta/cacert.pem' /* Informe a pasta onde você baixou/gerou seu certificado */
    ]
]);

$result = file_get_contents($url, FILE_BINARY, $stream);

$video_list = json_decode($result);

foreach($video_list->items as $item){;
    var_dump($item->snippet->title);
}
```

---

### Utilizando cURL

Uma outra possibilidade é utilizarmos o [*cURL*](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) para realizarmos requisições. Essa opção é mais robusta, mas fará, de forma semelhante, uma requisição.

Para configurarmos como deverá ser feita nossa requisição, precisamos usar a função `curl_setopt`. É nessa função que iremos informar se a requisição deve ser do tipo *POST* ou *GET*; Se poderemos "seguir" os redirecionamentos ou não; Se deveremos ignorar ou não o uso do certificado openssl e etc.

**Exemplo comentado:**

```
<?php

$dados = "Roberto Carlos";
$url   = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q='.urlencode($dados).'&maxResults=3&key=AIzaSyAVittweX_WS_VQYypeYl5uDSWl2ti7PMc';

/* Instancia o cURL e definimos a URL que desejamos passar */
$ch = curl_init($url);

/* Informamos que queremos receber o retorno da requisição */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

/**
 * Desabilita a necessidade do certificado, ignorando a segurança
 * Atenção: Remova a linha abaixo, caso você já tenha configurado o `php.ini`
 */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

/* Realizamos a requisição e obtermos o resultado */
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* Fechamos a requisição */
curl_close($ch);

$video_list = json_decode($result);

foreach($video_list->items as $item){;
    var_dump($item->snippet->title);
}
```

---

### Utilizando cURL com SSL

Caso você tenha limitações em seu servidor e não possa modificar o arquivo `php.ini`, você pode informar o local do certificado gerado/baixado na configuração da cURL:

**Exemplo comentado:**

```
<?php

$dados = "Roberto Carlos";
$url   = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q='.urlencode($dados).'&maxResults=3&key=AIzaSyAVittweX_WS_VQYypeYl5uDSWl2ti7PMc';

/* Instancia o cURL e definimos a URL que desejamos passar */
$ch = curl_init($url);

/* Informamos que queremos receber o retorno da requisição */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

/* Indique o local do arquivo *.pem que você baixou/gerou */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/path/to/cacert.pem");

/* Realizamos a requisição e obtermos o resultado */
$result = curl_exec($ch);

/* Fechamos a requisição */
curl_close($ch);

$video_list = json_decode($result);

foreach($video_list->items as $item){;
    var_dump($item->snippet->title);
}
```

Comment: Cara vc fez tudo muito muito obrigado agora entendi !

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php

$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$video_list = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=roberto&maxResults=3&key=AIzaSyAVittweX_WS_VQYypeYl5uDSWl2ti7PMc", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

echo $video_list;
?>
```

Agora preciso listar cada title estou fazendo assim mais ainda esta dando erro

```html
<?php foreach($video_list->items as $item){;?>
 
<?php echo $item->snippet->title;?><br>

<?php } ;?>
```